# Всплывающее окно при попытке закрытия сайта

Tags: javascript

Существует ли на данный момент рабочий способ, чтобы при попытке закрытия сайта всплывало окно с сообщением нужного текста, например, "Хочешь уйти?"?. Я много чего перечитал и перепробовал, особенно с onbeforeunload, и так ничего адекватного не нашел, окно всплывает с рандомным текстом (и во всех браузерах по-разному), и срабатывает при перезагрузке страницы и при переходе на какую-либо страницу сайта, в общем всё не то.
Может у кого-то есть какая-то интересная идея как сделать это окошко самому, если нет нормального решения?

Comment: Отображаемый текст вы не сможете поменять. А то, когда показывать это сообщение, решать вам.

Comment: вот неплохой вариант - https://github.com/carlsednaoui/ouibounce

Comment: или вот это вариант ? https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/Qrbbzy?editors=1000

Comment: Stepan Kasyanenko, так оно срабатывает и при переходе на другую страницу сайта и при перезагрузке страницы, если я правильно Вас понял. Как именно сделать, чтобы только при закрытии страницы работало?

Comment: Остальные способы срабатывают при потере фокуса... Всё не то...

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вроде этого:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
      document.write('<div>.....................</div>');  // HTML код в одну строчку!!!
      return "Вы точно решили покинуть наш сайт?";
      });

      $('a').click(function() {
      $(window).off('beforeunload');
    });
  });
 </script>
```